# Editar valor de chave no Registro do Windows e criar regra no firewall do windows com Python

Tags: python, windows

Preciso que um prejeto em python realize a alteração da porta no registro do windows (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet002\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber) e (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet001\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber) e crie uma regra de entrada e saida para essa mesma porta no Firewall dando permissões na porta, entretando não consgeui montar o código. Alguém poderia me indicar uma maneira correta de monta esse código? O código abaixo é o que iniciei com a regra do firewall entretando ele não está criando a regra, fiz vários testes esse foi o ultimo código que usei:

import os
import re
import winreg

porta = int(input('Informe a porta: '))
aspas = ("'")

portastr = str(porta)
portahera = '%x' % porta
liberacao = ('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="porta ts servidor" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=')
tcp = (aspas+liberacao+portastr+aspas)
os.system(tcp)
print(tcp)

Answer (score 0):

A parte do firewall consgeui resolver, usei o código abaixo, e após compilar, executei o exe como administrador e ficou ok, agora falta somente a parte da edição do registro, preciso alterar a porta no registro (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet002\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber) e (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet001\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber)

Segue o código do ajuste do firewall:
import os
import re
import winreg

porta = int(input('Informe a porta: '))

portastr = str(porta)
portahera = '%x' % porta
liberacao = ('netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="porta ts servidor" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=')
tcp = (liberacao+portastr)
os.system(tcp)